# Incorrect syntax error when creating view

Tags: sql-server

Error message returned:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vw_IVStockAging, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '–'.

When I execute this:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_IVStockAging
AS SELECT IV00101.ITEMNMBR AS ITEMNUMBER,
IV00101.ITEMDESC AS ITEMNAME,
...
(IV10200.QTYRECVD – IV10200.QTYSOLD) AS QTYAVAILABLE
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems pretty simple, you have a long dash (`–`) where you meant to have a minus sign (`-`). The difference is subtle to the human eye, but not to SQL Server.